# how to include weekends and holidays using apex class

Tags: apex, trigger, controller

I have requirement, where i need to check the day is workingday or holiday for that i got one class but problem here is that, i have written trigger handler from handler class how can i pass date and holiday list to below class can anyone help me and also i am getting error while calling this method like this "boolean holidycheck= holidaylist.changeWeekendTaskDueDate(evetstartdate ,holidays);"

```
  public boolean checkifItisWorkingDay(Date currentDate,List<Holiday> holidays)
{
                 Date weekStart  = currentDate.toStartofWeek();
                for(Holiday hDay:holidays)
                {
                        if(currentDate.daysBetween(hDay.ActivityDate) == 0)
                        {
                                 return false;
                        }
                }
               if(weekStart.daysBetween(currentDate) ==0 || weekStart.daysBetween(currentDate) == 6)
               {
                   return false;
                } else

               return true;
```

Below is my trigger handler class

```
List<Holiday> holidays=[Select h.StartTimeInMinutes, h.Name, h.ActivityDate From Holiday h];

        List<contact> conts  = (List<contact>) newSobjs;// 

        List<Event> events = new List<Event>();

        for (contact ri : conts )

        {

            Event evt = new Event(whatID = ri.ID);
            evt.Subject = 'Bid Due Date for ' + ri.name;  
            Date evetstartdate = ri.Completion_Date__c;
            boolean holidycheck= holidaylist.changeWeekendTaskDueDate(evetstartdate ,holidays);    
            evt.StartDateTime = evetstartdate;
            evt.DurationInMinutes= 30;  
            events.add(evt);

        }

        insert events;
```

Comment: Hmm, must you pass holidays like that?  Asking because there is a GUI setup in Salesforce to define BusinessHours and Holidays and you can reference them in code. See
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_businesshours.htm#apex_System_BusinessHours_methods

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customizesupport_holidays.htm&type=5

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_supporthours.htm&type=5

Comment: i got it thanks

Comment: public static Boolean IsWeekendDay(Date dateParam)
   {
      boolean result     = false;
      system.debug('dateParam = '+dateParam); 
      //Recover the day of the week
      Date startOfWeek   = dateParam.toStartOfWeek();
      system.debug('startOfWeek = '+startOfWeek);
      Integer dayOfWeek  = dateParam.day() - startOfWeek.day();
      system.debug('dayOfWeek = '+dayOfWeek);   
      result = dayOfWeek == 0 || dayOfWeek == 6 ? true : false;
      system.debug('result = '+result); 
      return result;
   } 
  along with holiday method it got sovled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a GUI setup in Salesforce for admins to define BusinessHours and Holidays and these configurations can be used in coded solutions. See https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customizesupport_holidays.htm&type=5